# Android having dependencies for library project

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, dependencies

I'm having android library project (name:mylibrary) (with maven setup) which depends on couple of maven dependencies (depend1, depend2). If I try to add my library project as dependency to any app (myapp), the following error occurs..

> failed to resolve depend1
>   failed to resolve depend2

It works, if add the dependencies in the app project (myapp). Otherwise, it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll check